# Jquery on click function not reseting on browser resize

Tags: jquery, resize, onclick

I have the following code which slides a column in a from left to right and nudges everything to the right of the column over to the right and then back again (a bit like facebook app).  It works fine on document ready but not on resize.  After resizing the it starts to act strangely.  Its as though its doing the previous function and not registering the new function on resize.

```
function doMenu() {

var $trigger = $(".icon-menu-2");
var $menu = $(".c_left");
var width = $(window).width();

if ((width < 870) && (width > 750)) {
    var status = 'closed';

    $('.icon-list').on('click', function(event){
        if ( status === 'closed' ){
            $menu.animate({
                width: 0,
                marginLeft: -200,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            $(".content_right, .navbar").animate({
                marginRight: 0,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            return status = 'open';

        } else if ( status === 'open' ) {
          $menu.animate({
                width: 200,
                marginLeft: 0,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            $(".content_right, .navbar").animate({
                marginRight: -120,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            return status = 'closed';
        }
    });
}

if (width < 750) {

   var status = 'closed';
    $('.icon-list').on('click', function(event){
        if ( status === 'closed' ){
            $menu.animate({
                width: 0,
                marginLeft: -200,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            $(".content_right, .navbar").animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            return status = 'open';

        } else if ( status === 'open' ) {
            $menu.animate({
                width: 200,
                marginLeft: 0,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            $(".content_right, .navbar").animate({
                marginLeft: 200,
                display: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');
            return status = 'closed';
        }
    });            

}

}
$(document).ready(doMenu);
$(window).resize(doMenu);
```

***EDIT** - changed toggle() to on('click', function(event) as suggested below but still have same problems with functions not working properly on resize.*

Comment: That version of `toggle()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9

Comment: Ok Ive tried to replace $trigger.toggle(function show() { with $trigger.click(function show() { but this does not work.  Can you help with what I need to change?  Many thanks

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.9 or newer, you'll need to create your own toggle functionality, as toggle() will only toggle the elements visiblity. click() on the other hand won't work out of the box either, as it has no toggle functionality, only one callback is available. You'll need to use click(), and create a toggle function with a flag or something similar.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, I am using 1.8 at the moment so will continue to use this for now until I have above functioning properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggle you can use flags.

```
var status = 'closed';
$('.foo').on('click', function(event){
    if ( status === 'closed' ){
        //...
        return status = 'open';

    } else if ( status === 'open' ) {
        //..
        return status = 'closed';

    }
});
```